# Many sports are popular in my country or Many sports in my country are popular?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Is there a difference between these two sentences or are they both correct?

-Many sports are popular in my country

-Many sports in my country are popular

Comment: Please suppl examples of the context in which you want to use these expressions. And please explain what problem you are trying to solve and what research you have already done to solve it. On their own they mean the same.

Comment: Well I’m not using this in something specific I just wanted to know the difference or if there is a special order I need to use in the sentences but if they both have the same meaning and are correct than thats all I needed to know thank you! @PeterJennings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these sentences are *correct*, but they mean two different things.

**Many sports are popular in my country** means that in your country, there are many sports that are popular. This is because "in my country" is an additional clause specifying *where* many sports are popular.

**Many sports in my country are popular** means that many sports from your country are popular (apparently in places other than your country). This sentence also reads a little bit more awkward then the other; you could correct it by saying **There are many sports in my country that are popular [elsewhere].** This is because "are popular" is added to the main clause, "[There are] many sports in my country."

I hope this helped :D

Comment: Thank you so much this really cleared it up for me!

Comment: Whilst you are technically correct, I think most native speakers would assume they meant the same thing. If you were trying to brag about your country you might say something like "Many popular sports originated / were invented in my country".